# Problem a friend has getting Error 438 all the time

Tags: excel, sorting, methods, properties

I sent a friend a workbook with a macro that includes some sorting.  When he tries it he gets:

> Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method.

He clicks Debug to see the offending code and is taken to a line or two of (fairly simple) data sorting.  The text that gets highlighted is:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Set").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
    "H2:H8065"), SortOn:=x1SortOnValues, Order:=x1Descending, DataOption:= _
    x1SortNormal
```

Those 3 lines are it, part of a larger sorting, and then copy/paste etc.
Works fine for me (Office 365).  He, in Chicago - I am in the UK - has maybe an older version of Windows.

Similar sorting occurs in other files I've sent him, and they work fine.  Would anyone know what I could alter to get rid of this 438 thing?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: you have some `x1...` that should be `xl...` that is with a lower case `L` not the number `1`

Comment: `SortFields.Add` instead of `.Add2`.

Comment: @BigBen I dont know much about this but why would Add2 not work?

Comment: Because it was added to the Excel Object Model in a later version... .so from the error message, that method is not supported in the friend's older version of Excel.

Comment: @BigBen Great! So if Add2 is not really needed as it seems here then for compatibility reasons its a good idea to use Add instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SortFields.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields.add) instead of the newer version [`SortFields.Add2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields.add2), which is not supported in older versions of Excel.

From the `.Add2` documentation:

> This API includes support for sorting off a SubField from data types, such as Geography or Stocks. You can also use the `Add` method if sorting by a data type is not needed.

... and you are not sorting by data type, so use `.Add`.